# Non-function do while loop in C

Tags: c, do-while, cs50, logical-or, logical-and

I'm new to programming and was hoping I could get some help. I'm attempting to create a 'do while' loop in C as part of my CS50 problem sets. I'm attempting to use two different conditions under 'while', but for some reason they are not being recognised. Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int get_height(void);

int main(void)

{
    int height = get_height();
    printf("you picked %i\n", height);
}

int get_height(void)
{
    int height;
    do
    {
        height = get_int("enter height\n");
    }
    while (height > 8 && height < 1);
    return height;
}
```

I'm trying to force the user to type an integer under 8, but above 0. If I take out either one of the two conditions, that single condition works. If I try to use both conditions however, the code compiles and runs but it doesn't force me to enter a number within the parameters specified. I can just enter any number and it will be accepted. Can anyone help?

EDIT:
I'm embarrassed. I misunderstood how AND operators work.

Comment: How will it ever be true that `height > 8` and `height < 1` ?

Comment: No point in being embarrassed. But do click the check mark next to one of the answers, so that everyone knows that the question has been answered. See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @user3386109 thanks, I was trying to do it shortly after the first reply but couldn't click it for a certain amount of time. Clicked it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that mathematics have not yet found an integer number that can be at the same time less than 1 and greater than 8.

```
while (height > 8 && height < 1);
```

It is evident you mean

```
while (height > 8 || height < 1);
```

But to make such a condition more clear for yourself it is useful sometimes to write at first the condition for which a number is being searched.

You need a number that lies in the range [1, 8] that is the target number shall satisfy the condition

```
1 <= height && height <= 8
```

In this case the condition in the do-while statement will be a negation of the condition above.

```
while ( !( 1 <= height && height <= 8 ) );
```

Now if to remove the negation you will have

```
while ( !( 1 <= height ) || !( height <= 8 ) );
```

that is equivalent to

```
while ( 1 > height || height > 8 );
```

So either use

```
while ( !( 1 <= height && height <= 8 ) );
```

pr

```
while ( 1 > height || height > 8 );
```

Answer (score 3):

Your condition says "continue the loop if `height` is larger than 8 AND `height` is smaller than 1".  That condition will never be true, so the loop exit after the first iteration.

What you want is "continue the loop if `height` is larger than 8 OR `height` is smaller than 1"

```
while (height > 8 || height < 1);
```

Comment: Oh my god I'm so stupid. Is this what being a programmer feels like?

Comment: @Disierd This is what being new at anything feels like, e.g. a gymnast falling off a balance beam before even starting a routine.

Answer (score 2):

These are mutually exclusive:

```
while (height > 8 && height < 1);
```

You probably want:

```
while (height > 8 || height < 1);
```

Now if the value is greater than 8 or smaller than 1, the loop will keep going.